# Backwards compatability considerations when moving from const std::string& to std::string_view?

Tags: c++, backwards-compatibility, string-view

I maintain a C++ library that frequently uses `const std::string&` arguments in its API. However, I have received some user requests to switch over to `std::string_view` to help enable efficiencies that wouldn't be possible with the current API.

I am considering simply replacing all instances of `const std::string&` arguments with `std::string_view` (possibly with a feature check that verifies that `std::string_view` is available). Will this break backwards compatibility for any of my users? I tried the simple replacement and it didn't seem to break anything in my code or tests, but of course that's not an exhaustive check.

<sup>I do realize that this will break some code that depends on the exact function signatures for my library. For the sake of simplicity, assume that I don't allow users to depend on the exact type signatures/arguments for my functions.</sup>

Comment: Do you ever depend on the fact that your arguments are currently null-terminated?

Comment: @Griwes No. Good catch though.

Comment: Just to point out: `std::string_view` doesn't allow to be constructed from `nullptr`.

Comment: @Jovibor Neither does std::string? The main difference seems to be that std::string_view fails at compile time but std::string fails at runtime. I guess that can cause issues if people are playing too many tricks with templates?

Comment: `std::string_view` fails at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I have attempted to replace `std::string const&` with `std::string_view` several times in my own code, and one of the following has always tripped me up:

- `std::string_view` never owns, so if any of your `std::string`-based code must own the character buffers for lifetime reasons, that part of the code cannot be converted to use `std::string_view`.  These issues can be subtle so care should be taken.
- Based on the first point, any code that requires ownership/`std::string` usage means that the efficiency gains you otherwise might have when using entirely `std::string_view` may not be fully realized.
- If you rely on null-terminated strings, then `std::string_view` is not a good candidate.  Pay close attention to any functions that might require `char const*` arguments, where an implicit assumption is made that the character buffer ends with `'\0'`.

If you can guarantee that all of the above conditions are met, then you're probably good to go with the `std::string` to `std::string_view` migration.